# How can I prevent the "Welcome to Android Development" wizard from appearing when I start Eclipse?

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse, android

I've written this on SuperUser as it's not a programming (programmers.se/stackoverflow) or Android-usage (android.se) question exactly.

The "Welcome to Android Development" wizard is a wizard which should pop up *on first run* of Eclipse after installing ADT Plugin. It allows you to select whether you want to send usage stats to Google. I don't mind one way or the other but it asks me every time I open Eclipse.

I'm on Linux Mint 14 (Nadia) x64. It's a new installation of Eclipse (Juno) from the Eclipse site, not from the software center. ADT is also on its latest version, freshly added using the update site from the Android dev page.

From the ADT changeset listed [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/292eefb8faa2f75ddbc5d6e20084c9f9a762da29%5E!/) it says:

```
...in particular it means the wizard won't be shown even if
you've wiped adtUsed=true from your ~/.android/ddms.cfg etc.
```

so I assumed that the `true` flag wasn't being correctly set in that file, but it is set. If I remove the file entirely, the popup still appears, and doesn't create a new one so perhaps it's entirely unrelated, but I'm not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well. I just had to completely erase the folder ~/.android as somehow I managed to create it with root privileges.
So delete it with root privileges and restart eclipse so that is generated with your personal privileges.

Comment: step by step instruction would be better

Comment: 1) Close eclipse and open terminal (ctrl + shift + t)
--
2) cd ~
--
3) sudo rm -rf .android
--
4) Reopen eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is just a guess, but it sounds like the program does not have the rights to read that config file. Perhaps it's running under different user creds or the permissions flags on the file/folder are not allowing it to read the flag from the file. Or maybe the program is looking in an entirely different folder for that file.